# Postgresql refreshing materialised view takes much longer than creating it

Tags: postgresql, performance, materialized-views

I have a materialized view which took 53 seconds to create with data, but refreshing it finished after over 6 minutes with file full error.
I do not ask about tmp file settings, but why I can create the file with data in 53 seconds, but refreshing it takes longer for no real reason.

This issue appeared after upgrade from v 11 to 13.

A Postgresql Materialized view with cardinality around 200k rows can be created with data in below minute, but cannot be refreshed.

Comment: Please share some details, we have no idea how your mat view looks like, what pg_stat_activity shows you, available disk space, etc. etc. A mat view is not a file anyway, so what is it exactly what you're doing? 53 seconds for a query is imho a lot, especially when you have just a 200k records. Did you check the query plan for the underlying query? Please check `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for the query inside your mat view.

Comment: 1) What where the times in the Postgres instance? 2) Did you [Analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) the database in the Postgres 13 instance after the upgrade?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, a materialized view is a file or files as it is persisted on disk like a table as shown by `select pg_table_size('some_mat_view'::regclass);`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm aware of that, but there is more going on then just the file(s) for this mat view. If the query is sorted on disk, lack of memory, you could be already almost out of disk space. When writing 200k records to disk, that could be just too much. Upgrade 11 to 13, suddenly a slow query and running out of disk space, it all sounds like a query plan that has changed and a configuration that has not been optimized for the new situation.

Comment: Was that `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ... CONCURRENTLY`?

Comment: your disks aren't full "up to the throat", are they?

Comment: thank you for the solution @AdrianKlaver